# What's a good, actively-developed status-bar-hosted mail client?

Tags: software-recommendation, applications, email, ios

I currently use [Notify](http://notifyapp.com/), but it has gone out from under active development and there are a few bugs in Lion. Is there something that does an identical or nearly identical thing, but hasn't been abandoned? Free would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sparrow](http://sparrowmailapp.com/) is $10 on the MAS and does have a status-bar only option.